# When using LoaderManager on Android should I paginate results?

Tags: android, pagination

Let say I have 1000 items on db, and I want to show them on a ListView using LoaderManager, should I load all these item at once ? or implement a pagination for instance 50 items, then when user scroll at the end get 50 more...

if the pagination is the right approach how do I implement it using LoaderManager?

Sample Loader Manager code:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(
                getActivity(),
                DbProvider.URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                Table.ID + " desc"
        );

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: one thousand or so shouldn't make any problem, you can skip pagination without any performance loss

Comment: @pskink lets say one million, if I had to implement pagination, which would be the approach using LoaderManager ?

Comment: One million you say? Then consider a custom AbstractWindowedCursor

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is always good if you have too many data. Trying to load lots of rows at once slows down rendering of the screen and its never a good user experience.

To implement pegination you could do something like this

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    //Check if the last view is visible
    if (++firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount > totalItemCount) {
        //LOAD MORE CONTENT HERE...
    }
}
});
```

Comment: yeah, but how do I add more items to listview/adapter when using LoaderManager ? when using `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query()` for instance I can add new items to adapter,  then calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` updates data. But how does it work for LoaderManager ?

Comment: I have never used LoaderManager so far but as much I know I think the code snippet I have mentioned should be used in `onLoadFinished` of the implementation of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`. I see you already have this method, try using my code in that. For now just put a log and see if that is displayed when listview scroll completes.